# OS X 10.5/10.6/10.7, Search, Spotlight

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, spotlight, search

I'm handling a migration from an on old Mac server to a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine running a 12 TB (10 usable) RAID 5 server. It's using an SMB share and now the OS X 10.5/10.6 users can search -  sometimes it works, but takes up to 10 minutes. The OS X 10.7 machine seems to be fine. I've looked in the root of the shared drive for a .Spotlight-V100 file (`ls -a`) but it doesn't seem to be there. `mdutil` says indexing is on for that volume and I have cleared the index using `mdutil -E /Volumes/MeSharedVolume` numerous times. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

SMB Shares are indexed locally by the client since SMB does not support remote queries by spotlight. You need to wait for each client to finish indexing to be able to search.

Comment: It's been over a week. Can I check if the index exists, where does it live?

Comment: Oh, and Thank you. That was useful. If I could at least find or not find the file I could see if it is indexing. I'm doing a job at this company that freaking out about their search.